# Bug in form working with PHP, MySQL and HTML

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

guys. I was going ok with my app until I got to this type of form, written below. I have 2 items in this table and the ID's are "1" and "2". Even though, if I press "Submit" on the "1" ID item, it prints me "2" every time. Does anyone have a clue what might be the problem? Thank you.

```
<form method="POST">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    while($row = $query->fetch_array())
    { 
        $id = $row['id'];
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

   <?php } ?>

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputting two items into the same form with the same name. When you click the **Submit** button, it gathers all of the fields in the form based on the *name* attribute and sends them on to wherever the form is being posted.

If you want to have a button that submits each ID with a separate button, you'd want to try having a new form for each ID. There are other ways of doing this too, but based on your current code, try something like this:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    while($row = $query->fetch_array())
    { 
        $id = $row['id'];
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
   <?php } ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
?>
```